# How to fix text-align, font size and actions column width on react Material Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-table

I have a MaterialTable in a React application and I need to align center the text on columns, fix the font size for the text on the columns. Also need to fix the width for the Actions column because the space between the actions column and the first data column seems more than desirable.

I have tried:

```
cellStyle: {text-align:'center', font-size='8'},
headerStyle: {text-align:'center', font-size='8'}
```

I need to align center the text on columns, set the font size of text and fix the width for the actions column on a React Material Table

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
display: flex;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction: column;
```

Comment: Thanks Maark but didn't work on the React Material Table

Answer (score 1):

When you are using JSX you need to change your css properties and remove the - and add the capital for the next word for example:

```
cellStyle: {text-align:'center', font-size='8'}
headerStyle: {text-align:'center', font-size='8'}
```

should become

```
cellStyle: {textAlign:'center', fontSize='8'}
headerStyle: {textAlign:'center', fontSize='8'}
```

Comment: Thanks, but didnt work. I have this: <div>
            <MaterialTable
                title="Select"
                tableRef={this.tablePO}
                columns={[
                              
                { title: 'Pedido', field: 'PO_Number'   cellStyle: 
        {textAlign:'center', fontSize='8'}, headerStyle: {textAlign:'center', fontSize='8'}} ]}                                                          
               
                data={[
                    {  PO_Number: this.state.dataMe2l.PO_Number}
                 ]}   />

Comment: could you put your code in a sandbox to try to help you

Comment: of course Cristobal Soto, Im newbie to React, javascript, I have this code https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-https-dtqh0 but dont show on the codesandbox browser